# MS Access: Update a table field from a query field

Tags: ms-access

I have a field in a table called "CaseDelay" and a field in a query called "Delay." Both are numbers.

Don't know the best procedure to get the query to run and the field value to update the table field.

Additionally, the field in the query is a calculated field, and I read on Microsoft's website that syntax such as UPDATE won't work with calculated fields.

The expressions that are in the query are difficult nested IIF statements that I couldn't figure out how to write in VBA, but could do it in a query expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll first need to specify how the records in the query relate to those in the table, such that an `update` query can unambiguously identify & update the appropriate record in your table for each record in your query.

Typically this would be achieved using unique keys present in both the table & query which may be used to pair up the records in the two datasets.

Once this is ascertained, assuming that the query does not use aggregation, you can use a straightforward `update` query with a join between your existing query & table, e.g.:

```sql
update YourTable inner join YourQuery on YourTable.ID = YourQuery.ID
set YourTable.CaseDelay = YourQuery.Delay
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error. Here is the subroutine I entered:  <br/>
`Private Sub CaseDelay_GotFocus()
update tbl.Assigned_Cases inner join qry_Case_Delay on tbl.Assigned_Cases.ID = qry_Case_Delay.ID
Set tb.Assigned_Cases.CaseDelay = qry_Case_Delay.Delay
End Sub`<br/>
Sorry that I can't figure out how to put breaks in a comment.

Comment: @Jasuan You cannot just copy SQL code into a VBA Sub - VBA & SQL are two different programming languages. If you want to execute the SQL from VBA, either use `DoCmd.RunSQL` or `CurrentDb.Execute`, or copy the SQL to a saved query and use `DoCmd.OpenQuery`. Aside, `tbl.Assigned_Cases` is not a valid table name (table names cannot contain periods), and you have a typo later on in the code in which you refer to this same table as `tb.Assigned_Cases`

Comment: can the saved query be the one I am updating from ("rqy_Case_Dealy")?

Comment: I got the code to work. Here is the final product:  <br/> `Private Sub Mailout_LostFocus()
Dim SQLText As String
SQLText = "update tbl_Assigned_Cases inner join qry_Case_Delay on tbl_Assigned_Cases.CaseID = qry_Case_Delay.CaseID Set tbl_Assigned_Cases.CaseDelay = qry_Case_Delay.Delay"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLText
End Sub`  <br/> One annoying thing is I get the warning every time that I am updating "X" number of Rows. Can I either A) update only the active record, or B) add some code to automatically click "Yes" on the pop-up?

Comment: Lee, running into  a slight problem. When the command runs, it updates all records. However, when I make a change to a record that changes the value in the query, it will not update the CaseDelay field with the revised number. For example, I made a change in one of the date fields in the table. The query updated the Delay field from 15 to 22. However, the table still shows 15.  I make sure to prompt the command to run and get the pop up saying X number of rows have been updated.

Comment: You can suppress the warning using `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` or by disabling confirmation of action queries within the Access Options menu. Regarding your issue, without sample data it is difficult to advise. I would suggest creating a new question explaining the issue in detail.

Comment: the `SetWarnings` command worked great. Will post a new question for the update issues.

Comment: I figured out the updating issue. I need to set a save macro as an AfterUpdate event.